# Inequality with two binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am having trouble seeing why

$$
\binom{k}{2} + \binom{n - k}{2} \le \binom{1}{2} +   \binom{n - 1}{2} = \binom{n - 1}{2}
$$

Comment: You need some condition on $k$, otherwise $k=n$ makes the inequality false.

Comment: Yes, I missed that 0<k<n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $0\lt k\lt n$, induction gives us

$$\begin{align}
{k\choose2}+{n+1-k\choose2}&={k\choose2}+{n-k\choose2}+{n-k\choose1}\\
&\le{n-1\choose2}+{n-k\choose1}\\
&\le{n-1\choose2}+{n-1\choose1}\\
&={n\choose2}
\end{align}$$

while ${k\choose2}+{n+1-k\choose2}\le{n\choose2}$ holds trivially if $k=n$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $1\le n$ and $0\le k\le n$ it's equivalent to
\begin{align*}k(k-1)+(n-k)(n-k-1)&\le(n-1)(n-2)\\
(n-k)(n-k-1)&\le(n-k-1+k)(n-2)-k(k-1)\\
(n-k)(n-k-1)&\le(n-k-1)(n-2)+k(n-2)-k(k-1)\\
0&\le(n-k-1)(k-2)+k(n-k-1)\\
0&\le(n-k-1)(k-1)\end{align*}
So it holds for all $0<k<n$.